# How would I click this image link in Selenium when there is no id?

Tags: java, html, selenium, webdriver

I am trying to click to go to where the href is referencing. I am not sure what code I would accomplish this with since there is no apparent id. Keep in mind the link referenced by href can change at any time.

```
<ul style="display: block; max-height: 230px; width: 129px; margin: auto; transition: all 500ms ease-in-out 0s;" id="pubCarousel" class="elastislide-list"><li style="width: 100%; max-width: 129px; max-height: 230px;">
                <a href="/MTR/FBSC/en/36548659-040e-4185-9ad7-c9472d8fc36e/Page?storeId=bfd80755-bbfa-49b4-92ac-2f62ee2d1f83&amp;postalCode=P3E3Z9">
                    <img src="http://mtr.ca.flyerservices.com/cached_images/pages/FBSC_45e00411-b791-44f7-8310-a77dc39d4fbd_111_53284_FB_E_01_B1_V1_E18.p1.jpg" alt="" border="0">
                    <p class="caption">
                        <span class="title">Version 1</span>
                        <br>
                        <span>July 16, 2015 to July 22, 2015</span>
                    </p>
                </a>
            </li></ul>
```

Comment: There are other ways also to find elements using selenium. For example you can use css selector: By.cssSelector("img[src^=''http://mtr.ca.flyerservices.com/cached_images']") or you can use By.tagName("img"), or you can use xPath, or you can search for the anchor tag.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As skandigraun said in his comment there are other ways to find elements using Selenium. I have often had to use a CSS selector as well as xpath selectors.

For finding the CSS or xpath you need for the selector I usually use chrome developer tools or firebug to right click -> "Inspect element" followed by a right click on the desired element -> "Copy CSS path" or "Copy XPath"

```
driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("#pubCarousel li a img")).click();
```

or for XPath

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id=\"pubCarousel\"]/li/a/img")).click();
```

I am unfortunately away from my computer so I can't test them out right now. The XPath one should work for you, but I'm not sure if the CSS one will without a little tweaking.

Comment: The second one worked. For the record I didn't try out the first one so it may also be correct. Thanks man.

Comment: I'm glad it worked for you! Selenium can be a really powerful tool once you get used to it.